# UIWebViews in UIPageViewController wrong pagination

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, pagination, uipageviewcontroller

I have several web views with loaded content paginated horizontally. I have these web views in page view controller to provide fluent horizontal paging. Everything works fine, but only problem is at the edge of view controllers in page view controller. When user swipes to new view controller and right after that again quickly forward, page view controller scrolls to next view controller instead of turning page on web view.

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    print("next view controller")
    let viewController = pageViewController.viewControllers!.first as! WebViewController
    if viewController.loaded {
        return previousViewController
    }
    return nil
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    print("previous view controller")
    let viewController = pageViewController.viewControllers!.first as! WebViewController
    if viewController.loaded {
        return nextViewController
    }
    return nil
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionToViewControllers pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
    print("will transition")
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    print("did finish \(finished), completed \(completed)")
    if completed {
        let webViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first as? WebViewController
        if webViewController == nextViewController {
            currentSpineIndex++
            if let newNextViewController = loadWebViewControllerAtSpineIndex(currentSpineIndex + 1) {
                nextViewController = newNextViewController
            } else {
                nextViewController = nil
            }
            previousViewController = previousViewControllers.first as? WebViewController
        } else if webViewController == previousViewController {
            currentSpineIndex--
            if let newPreviousViewController = loadWebViewControllerAtSpineIndex(currentSpineIndex - 1) {
                previousViewController = newPreviousViewController
            } else {
                previousViewController = nil
            }
            nextViewController = previousViewControllers.first as? WebViewController
        }
    }
}
```